# Flutter Instance of 'Future<Translation>' i keep getting this on my print

Tags: flutter, dart, translate, timeago

i trying to translate a string and show it to my screen but when i try to check the text on print it say `Instance of Future<Translation>`

this is my code when i try to use then(print)

```
 final finalLastSeen = translator
            .translate(timeago.format(userLastSeen), from: 'en', to: 'id')
            .then(print);
```

it show the string that i want. but when i make this

```
 final finalLastSeen = translator.translate(timeago.format(userLastSeen),
            from: 'en', to: 'id');

        print(finalLastSeen);
```

it will show the Future error

this is my whole FutureBuilder Code

```
 return FutureBuilder(
      future: users.doc(product.userId).get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
          return const Text("Document does not exist");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data =
              snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          _sellerImageurl = '${data['imageUrl']}';
          _sellerName = '${data['name']}';
          _sellerJoinedDate = '${data['createdAt']}';
          _sellerCity = '${data['location']}';
          _sellerStatus = '${data['status']}';
          _sellerLastSeen = '${data['lastSeen']}';
        }

       final DateTime lastSeen = DateTime.parse(_sellerLastSeen);
        final Duration _sellerTimePassed = time.difference(lastSeen);
        final userLastSeen = DateTime.now().subtract(_sellerTimePassed);
        final _userOffline = '';
        print(timeago.format(userLastSeen));

          final finalLastSeen = await translator.translate(timeago.format(userLastSeen),
              from: 'en', to: 'id');

          print(finalLastSeen);


        return product_details_layout(
          cartProvider: cartProvider,
          product: product,
          productId: productId,
          wishListProvider: wishListProvider,
          sellerImageurl: _sellerImageurl,
          sellerName: _sellerName,
          sellerCity: _sellerCity,
          sellerStatus: _sellerStatus,
          userOffline: _userOffline,
          productList: productList,
          sellerJoinedDate: _sellerJoinedDate,
        );
      },
    );
``
```

Comment: because it is an instance of future. you need to use ``await`` keyword before ``translator.translate`` as ``await  translator.translate``

Comment: but when i add the async  my whole page become error, is it because i using it on FutureBuilder?

Comment: ``translator.translate(..)`` is already ``async``, you need to use the ``await`` keyword which will wait until the async method returns a value.

Comment: it show me this `The await expression can only be used in an async function.
Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'.`

Comment: you can't use the await in a future builder, at least like you're trying to do :/

Answer (score 0):

The translate is an async function.

The `then` is waiting for the translate function to complete and return your `Translation`.

In the second case, you have no `then` so you are not waiting for it to complete and you just have a `Future<Translation`.

You can do this instead:

```
final finalLastSeen = await translator.translate(timeago.format(userLastSeen),
            from: 'en', to: 'id');
print(finalLastSeen);
```

The `await` will make sure you are waiting for the function to complete before you call the print.

Answer (score 0):

You should take care of `async/await`. Please take look at [here](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await). If you are getting printed like `Instance of Future<anything>` that means you are not waiting for the asynchronous to fulfill. Your code should look like this.

```dart
/// for printing promise result
translator.translate(timeago.format(userLastSeen), from: 'en', to: 'id')
            .then(print);
/// or by await
final finalLastSeen = await translator
            .translate(timeago.format(userLastSeen), from: 'en', to: 'id');
print(finalLastSeen);

/// inside widget you can use FutureBuilder
widget(
 child: FutureBuilder(
    future: translator.translate(timeago.format(userLastSeen), from: 'en', to: 'id'),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) => snapshot.hasData ? Text(snapshot.data):Text("Waiting...")
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see some example from the [Translator package example](https://pub.dev/packages/translator/example).

So, if you want to have the string as result, use `async` methode and put `await` keyword before `translator.translate`:

```
void myMethod() async {
  final finalLastSeen = await translator.translate(timeago.format(userLastSeen), from: 'en', to: 'id');
  print(finalLastSeen);
}
```